# I delete " } else { } " but the code is still correct?

Tags: if-statement, return, conditional-statements

```
if (condition a) {
    return (result b)
} else {
    return (result c)
}
```

once I delete " }else{ } the code become

```
if (condition a) {
    return (result b)
} 
return (result c)
```

why the second code still make the same function as the first?

For me, in the second one, it will anyway runs the `return (result c)` however, it's not the case!

Any clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens in each example...

In the first example:

- If `condition a` is `true` then the code inside that block will be executed, returning `result b` and exiting the function.
- If the condition is not true, then the code inside the `else` block will be executed, returning `result c` and exiting the function.

In the second example:

- If `condition a` is `true` then the code inside that block will be executed, returning `result b` and exiting the function.
- If the condition is not true, then control will continue past the `if` block and execute the next code, returning `result c` and exiting the function.

Logically the two are the same.  In this specific case, including the `else` is just a matter of personal preference.

> For me, in the second one, it will anyway runs the return `(result c)`

Not if the function has already returned a result and exited.  Then remaining code in the function is not executed, because it's already returned.

Answer (score 0):

In most languages `return (something)` does two things:

1. define the return value of the current function/method/...
2. end the control flow of the current function/method/... and return to the caller.

It's the item #2 that means that even without the `else` the two pieces of code do essentially the same thing:

Since the code block warded by the `if` statement never completes normally, but instead returns to the caller the code after it will not be executed, when the `if` block is executed.